# Categories work on dev server but not live server

Tags: ee2, categories

We've just moved a site from the dev server to the live server and everything seems to be fine. However, the categories filtering on the blog doesn't seem to be working.

The URLs generated are:

```
/blog/category/recipes
```

The sidebar code for the categories is:

```
<h3>Categories</h3>
<ul>
  {exp:channel:categories channel="blog" style="linear"}
  <li><a href="{path='blog/index'}">{category_name}</a></li>
  {/exp:channel:categories}
</ul>
```

The stripped down channel entries tag for "blog/index" is:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" orderby="entry_date" sort="desc" limit="5"}
{if no_results}No results{/if}
<section class="blog-overview">
    <h2>{title}</h2>
    <div class="extract-text">
      {blog_main_content:excerpt}
    </div>
  <p class="publish-date">Published on {entry_date format="%l %j %F %Y"}</p>
</section>    
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

What could I have missed during the site move? Where should I start looking to troubleshoot this?

Thanks for any advice

EE2.5.5

**EDIT:**
Archives seems to be filtering though:

```
/blog/archives/2013/04

{exp:channel:month_links channel="blog" limit="12"}
    <li><a href="{path='blog/archives'}">{month} {year}</a></li>
{/exp:channel:month_links}
```

Comment: Do you have some form of redirect or URL rewrites going on that's using something in an htaccess file?

Comment: we have NSM .htaccess Generator and 'Detour Pro 1.3.2'. Just been told that 'Detour Pro' was not installed on the dev server - only the live server so it could redirect all the old URLs to their new locations.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with those really but I would check that any redirects in the htaccess files are correct for the new server.

Comment: I uninstalled Detour Pro and Removed the htaccess file altogether and the categories filtering still didn't work

Comment: archives seem to be working though

Comment: Removing the htaccess may not fix the issue (if this is indeed the issue). If there are redirects in the htaccess that make the categories work but are specific to the server then when you moved your site the redirects may no longer work.


Why not post your original htaccess (from the working site) here so we can see if this is indeed the issue?

Comment: here is the htaccess from the dev site - where the category filtering worked: http://pastebin.com/SU2EJjMk

Comment: Fixed it! Someone had turn "Break on category URL indicator" in the Freebie extension to "Yes". As soon as that was set back to "no" categories filtering started working again. Thank you so much @foamcow for taking the time to try and help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by a misconfiguration of the Freebie extension.

The `Break on category URL indicator` had been set to "Yes" which meant that Freebie was overwriting EE's native functionality for processing `/channel/category/category-name`